# Drawbacks of Cure algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

i searched a lot but could not find the drawbacks of Cure algorithm. Are they any limitations of Cure clustering algorithm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Taking This Explanation from the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURE_data_clustering_algorithm) on the cure algorithm

The short answer is **runtime complexity**

- The Running Time is O(n^2 log(n))
- The Space Complexity is O(n)

For database applications, this is a pretty high runtime complexity, so you may have issues applying it directly to large databases

According to Wikipedia, this limitation can be mitigated using the following methods

> - Random sampling : random sampling supports large data sets. Generally the random sample fits in main memory. The random sampling involves a trade off between accuracy and efficiency.
> - Partitioning : The basic idea is to partition the sample space into p partitions. Each partition contains n/p elements. The first pass partially clusters each partition until the final number of clusters reduces to n/pq for some constant q ≥ 1. A second clustering pass on n/q partially clusters partitions. For the second pass only the representative points are stored since the merge procedure only requires representative points of previous clusters before computing the representative points for the merged cluster. Partitioning the input reduces the execution times.
> - Labeling data on disk : Given only representative points for k clusters, the remaining data points are also assigned to the clusters. For this a fraction of randomly selected representative points for each of the k clusters is chosen and data point is assigned to the cluster containing the representative point closest to it.